# C++ Protected member access

Tags: c++

need a protected class made to access month day year I understand you need to create a class from the inherited class and not call the protected data in main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class dateType
{
   public:
      dateType();
      dateType(int, int, int);
      void setDate(int, int, int);
      void printDate(ostream&)const; 


   protected:
      int month;
      int day;
      int year;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const dateType &d) {
   os << d.month << "/" << d.day << "/" << d.year; 
   files 

      return os;
}
```

when this code executes I get an error saying month, day and year are protected

Comment: You can get answers to your problems in [any good text book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Why c++11 tag ?

Answer (score 1):

Code with friend operator <<.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class dateType
{
public:
    dateType();
    dateType(int, int, int);
    void setDate(int, int, int);
    void printDate(ostream&)const;

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const dateType &d) {
        os << d.month << "/" << d.day << "/" << d.year;
        return os;
    }


protected:
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};
```

Comment: I would argue with your _"have to"_. As well, one can make `operator<<` a `friend`, which might be better solution if getters are otherwise not needed.

Comment: Agreed with you.

Answer (score 0):

Your method should be friend like this:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const dateType &d) 
{
    os << d.getMonth() << "/" << d.getDay() << "/" << d.getYear();
    return os;
}
```

In your class implementation